# Python reading datetime string ( reading T01:00:00-07:00 with python )

Tags: python

Has anyone converted this kind of times before?

```
2020-10-12T01:00:00-07:00 to 2020-10-12T09:00:00-07:00
```

equals

```
Monday, October 12, 2020 at 10:00 AM – 6:00 PM UTC+02
```

to datetime objects?

Comment: It doesn't no T09:00:00-07:00 how to read after T?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: Do some research and show us something that you tried and didn't work

Comment: I have no idea how to read T01:00:00-07:00

Comment: It's one date not multiple one date

Comment: @Tomerikoo that is my question exactly

Comment: Those "kind of times" are called "ISO8601" times, and they are standardized. Please do some reading on ISO8601 first, and afterwards you should easily find libraries that can handle ISO8601 times.

Comment: Neither of those two questions put forward to close this as a dupe actually show how to *parse* and ISO8601 string, they simply deal with creating one. Voting to re-open.

Comment: are you showing the results of local time?

Answer (score 1):

> `2020-10-12T01:00:00-07:00`
> `<--date--> <-time-><zone>`

This means `1am` on `October 12th, 2020`, in the time zone 7 hours west of UTC (running through the [middle of the US](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/map/), basically).

It's actually one of the [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats, used for date/time data interchange.

I believe the [`dateutil.parser()`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library can handle this in Python.